# How do I find a POSIX locale from some of its specifications?

Tags: posix, locale

Installing a new Debian, I want the system to have:

```
metric system (not imperial)
$ as currency symbol
. as decimal separator
, (or space) as thousands separator
YYYY-MM-DD (or DD/MM/YYYY) as date format
A4 (not Letter) as default paper size
```

and so on.

However, I haven't found a complete list of specifications for any given locale. I've found [this site](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/en-001/index.html), but it says nothing about metric system vs. imperial, or default paper size.

Even better would be to found a list of locales from the specifications given above. Does such a search tool even exist?

Answer (score 1):

Locale categories of the form **LC_*xxx*** exist for configuring this kind of information, and there are environment variables with the same names as those locale categories.  Basically, you find a locale that has the desired properties you want and set the environment variable(s) controlling those properties to that locale.  Unfortunately, you don't know whether it does what you want until you try it or look up whether that locale's configuration will work for you.  I'm not aware of any tool that will allow you to find and set the relevant environment variables based on the format(s) you specify.

POSIX systems rely on the **LANG** environment variable to set the default values of these locale categories, and the **LC_*xxx*** environment variables are used to override **LANG**.  For example, my **LANG** is set to `en_US.UTF-8`, but my **LC_COLLATE** is set to `C.UTF-8` because I prefer case-sensitive sort order when I look at output from utilities like `ls` and `sort`; this means that the values of all other **LC_*xxx*** categories are set to `en_US.UTF-8` on my system, which can be verified by running [locale(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages/locale.1.en.html):

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

You can temporarily override settings for a command to test whether it does what you want:

```
$ date +'%x'
04/03/2021
$ LC_TIME='en_CA.UTF-8' date +'%x'
2021-04-03
$ LC_TIME='en_GB.UTF-8' date +'%x'
03/04/2021
```

Below are the relevant categories and some example values that provide most of what you want, though not all of the locales below may be enabled on all systems:

| Name | Value | Sample | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **LC_MONETARY** | `en_US.UTF-8` | $1,234,567.89 | Locale for monetary values |
| **LC_NUMERIC** | `en_US.UTF-8` | 1,234,567.89 | Locale for numeric values |
| **LC_TIME** | `en_CA.UTF-8` | 2021-04-03 | Locale for dates and times |
| **LC_TIME** | `en_GB.UTF-8` | 03/04/2021 | (see above) |

Paper size is usually handled by the printing system (e.g. CUPS), and metric/imperial is typically a per-application setting.  However, you mentioned Debian, and GNU Libc does support non-POSIX locale categories to control paper size and measurement.  For more information about these and other locale categories, see [locale(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages/locale.5.en.html) and [locale(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages/locale.7.en.html). As these are nonstandard, support for them is likely limited to systems with GNU Libc.

As previously stated, not all possible locales are necessarily supported on all systems.  On systems with GNU Libc, you want to use [locale-gen(8)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/locales/locale-gen.8.en.html) to generate the necessary locales if they're not already enabled, assuming you have superuser permissions.  You can list the available locales using `locale -a`; again, see [locale(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages/locale.1.en.html) for more info.